# What does it take to built an Auto Alignment for elements like NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, applet, layout-manager

Currently I have a java applet tools for users to design GUI. The user is able to choose what element (TextBox, ComboBox, JTable and etc) drag and drop elements on top of a design area. An element can be moved, resized, and change properties.

I have been struggling to do one more thing: Element Auto Alignment

In NetBeans, when a user drags an element around the design area, it will snap to align with the existing element  (and additional ruler underline to show the user that it is currently align with this element)

Any idea how to develop this in Java applet?

Comment: "*TextBox, ComboBox, JTable and etc"*  `TextBox` no such thing in the J2SE. `ComboBox` AWT?  `JTable` - Swing, obviously.  Please clarify the first two.  Auto-alignment is usually done using layouts.